# Divide a circle in N parts by N-1 choords with areas proportional to some data

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I have a circle with radius $r$ and area $Area$.
Suppose I want to divide this circle in $N$ parts using $(N-1)$ parallel chords basing on percentages.

I explain it better with an example:

$N = 5$

$datum1=25$,
$datum2=5$,
$datum3=10$,
$datum4=50$,
$datum5=10$

So the sum of the data is $100$.

What I would like to obtain is a circle divide by 4 parallel chords that divide the circle area in 5 parts: each area part should be proportional to the datum.

[image]

In this example:

- the yellow area should be 25% of $Area$
- the pink area should be 5% of $Area$
- the purple area should be 10% of $Area$
- the red area should be 50% of $Area$
- the blue area should be 10% of $Area$

To draw that parts, I need to know the 4 point on the perpendicular diameter to the choord ($A, B, C, D$).
How can I find that points?

I don't know how to start, I'm sure that I can't simply compute that points as percentage of the diameter because the area of the parts is important.

Comment: Thanks for the problem ! I had a lot of fun with it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @heropup answered, there is no analytical solution for
$$f=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y\sqrt{1-y^2} +\sin ^{-1}(y)}{\pi }$$ but we can build very good approximations.

First of all, to introduce symmetry, let $k=\pi  \left(f-\frac{1}{2}\right)$. So, we focus on
$$k=y\sqrt{1-y^2} +\sin ^{-1}(y)\tag 1$$

For example, building the Taylor series around $y=0$
$$k=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,y^{2n+1}$$ where the $a_n$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{2,-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{20},-\frac{1}{56},-\frac{5}{576},-\frac{7}{1408},-
   \frac{21}{6656},-\frac{11}{5120},-\frac{429}{278528},\cdots\right\}$$ which is a very good approximation.

Now, using series reversion, we should get
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^p b_n\,k^{2n+1}$$ where the $b_n$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{48},\frac{13}{3840},\frac{493}{645120},\frac{37369}{185
   794560},\frac{4732249}{81749606400},\frac{901188997}{51011754393600},\cdots\right\}$$

Even if it does not mean too much, using the above terms, the difference between lhs and rhs in $(1)$ is $1.12\times 10^{-5}\, k^{15}$

As  @heropup did, trying with the above terms for $f=\frac 13$ (that is to say  $k=-\frac \pi 6$) will give $y=-0.2649320842$ while the "exact" solution is        $y=-0.2649320846$.

Fore sure, we could even do better but, using a reasonable  estimate such as $$\color{blue}{y_0=k\frac{240-29 k^2}{480-78 k^2}}$$ for example, Newton method converges so fast that it would a pitty not to use it directly. This estimate corresponds to the Taylor series to $O(k^7)$.

For sure, these approximations become worse when $y \to 1$ (that is to say $k=\frac \pi 2$. For this region, we can better use
$$k\sim \frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2} (1-y)^{3/2}\implies \color{blue}{y_0=1-\sqrt[3]{ \frac{9}{128} (\pi -2 k)^2}}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit late but what $f=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y\sqrt{1-y^2} +\sin ^{-1}(y)}{\pi }$ is? What it does represent? How was it calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your question does not have a simple closed-form solution.  For a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin on a Cartesian coordinate plane, a horizontal line at $y = y_0$ cuts the circle into two areas such that the fraction of the total area within the circle that is below the line is $$f(y_0) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{y_0 \sqrt{1-y_0^2} + \sin^{-1} y_0}{\pi}, \quad -1 < y_0 < 1.$$  A suitable scaling transformation allows us to generalize to any positive radius $r$.  But your question is asking how to find $y_0$ that yields a desired value of $f(y_0)$.  That is to say, you want to find the inverse function of $f$.  But such an inverse does not have a closed form.

If you can use a computer, Newton's method can be applied to numerically compute the inverse.  For a given fraction $a$ of the circle's area we wish to enclose between $y = -1$ and $y = y_n$, we seek the root of $g(y) = f(y) - a = 0$, for which the recursion $$y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{g(y_n)}{g'(y_n)} = \frac{\pi(1-2a) \sqrt{1-y_n^2}+2 y_n^3+2 \sqrt{1-y_n^2} \sin ^{-1}y_n - 2 y_n}{4 \left(y_n^2-1\right)}$$ with initial guess $y_0 = 0$ yields a sequence of approximations $\{y_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ that converges to the desired $y$-value.  For example, if we set $a = 1/3$, so that we want a horizontal line that divides the unit circle into a ratio of $1 : 2$ with the smaller area being below the line, then we get the table $$\begin{array}{c|cc}
 n & y_n & f(y_n) \\
\hline
 0 & 0. & 0.5 \\
 1 & -0.2617993877991494 & 0.3352572612077344 \\
 2 & -0.2649306995458483 & 0.3333341835804551 \\
 3 & -0.2649320846025036 & 0.3333333333335011 \\
 4 & -0.2649320846027769 & 0.3333333333333333 \\
 5 & -0.2649320846027769 & 0.3333333333333333
\end{array}$$
It doesn't take very many iterations to get good precision, due to the fact that $f$ is roughly linear across most of its domain.  Then to get each division line, you would first calculate the cumulative list of percentages; e.g., from the bottom to the top, your example would have $a_1 = 0.1, a_2 = 0.6, a_3 = 0.7, a_4 = 0.75$.  This gives us the table of $y$-values
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
a_i & y_0 \\
\hline
 0.1 & -0.687049 \\
 0.6 & 0.157736 \\
 0.7 & 0.319692 \\
 0.75 & 0.403973
\end{array}$$

Comment: Why the fraction of the total area within the circle that is below the line is not easily $\frac{1}{2} \pi r^2$?